# How do I know my X-Cart website version is 4.5

Tags: x-cart

I updated my X-Cart from 4.4.2 to 4.5 .
But after updated it, version number is not showing on Admin panel.

Is there anyway to check is my X-Cart is exactly 4.5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out the version of your X-Cart installation using one of the following links:

X-Cart's files version:
http://[your_site_URL]/[xcart_dir]/VERSION

X-Cart's database version:
http://[your_site_URL]/[xcart_dir]/include/version.php

for example:

http://demo.x-cart.com/demo_goldplus/VERSION

http://demo.x-cart.com/demo_goldplus/include/version.php